# Required parameters

Tags: php

I have problem when I am trying to access registration page of my application. I use `PHP Version 7.0.5`. 
**URL :** http://localhost/project/registration.php 
**PARAMS :** name, email and password 
but unfortunatelly I got error message `Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!` 
this is my code :

```
$registration = new user(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

// json response
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

$name = (isset($_POST['name'])) ? $_POST['name'] : FALSE;
$email = (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : FALSE;
$password = (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : FALSE;

if (isset($name) && isset($email) && isset($password)) {

    //$name = $_GET['name'];
    //$email = $_GET['email'];
    //$password = $_GET['password'];

    // check if user is already existed with the same email
    if ($registration->isUserExisted($email)) {
        // already existed
        $response["error"] = TRUE;
        $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed with " . $email;
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $user = $registration->storeUser($name, $email, $password);
        if ($user) {
            // user stored successfully
            $response["error"] = FALSE;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else  {
            // user failed to store
            $response["error"] = TRUE;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Unknown error occurred in registration!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

} else {
    $response["error"] = TRUE;
    $response["error_msg"] = "Required parameters (name, email or password) is missing!";
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Could anyone help to me ? Why I got this error.

Comment: Have you tried to do a `var_dump();` on your three variables to see what they actually contain?

Comment: please print the var_dump($_POST) here.

Comment: @Epodax i got NULL message

Comment: Well there's the issue, you never get them to true.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is always set, but its content might be empty.

```
$var = '';

// This will evaluate to TRUE so the text will be printed.
if (isset($var)) {
    echo "This var is set so I will print.";
}
```

As Epodax mentioned try using var_dump();

Comment: i got NULL message